# Save credit card number on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, stripe-payments

I was wondering if it was safe to do the following:

I have a multi-page form (done with jquery so there are no server requests in between pages).

On the second page the user inputs his credit card information.
On the third (last) page the user confirms all information entered on the previous two pages (like a summary).

When the user clicks on the next button on page two, the following script runs:

```
$("#payment-next").click(function(){
    var ccNumber = $("#card_number").val();
    //If credit card invalid
    if(!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNumber)){
      //Throw error 
    }
});
```

The `ccNumber` variable is also used on page three where all the information is confirmed.

Is it correct and secure to store the credit card number on the `ccNumber` variable? Where is that variable stored?

Comment: ccNumber is a local variable and will not exist after the click ended. You can however save the variable somehow, there are many ways, you can look into local storage if you like or even the session.

Comment: thanks Chris. if i make ccNumber a global variable on the script for that page, is it safe from being accessed by someone?

Comment: is this a single page app?

Comment: what i described above happens all in one page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really do that much about client side, so long as it's asyn I suppose and that you do not have name attributes on the inputs.

I really wouldn't make it global, and please look into `Stripe.js`.

https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/switching.

Comment: OP is doing it all on the client's browser. The methods proposed above  safely posts the card data to Stripe which will return a card object or an errors object. All while being PCI compliant.

Comment: That's what Stripe does, it integrates into your app/site so the user doesn't have to leave your site. The OP is clearly using `Stripe.card.validateCardNumber` which checks the CC number with the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), and is asking if it's okay to keep the number on the same page, no redirects, just changing the content dynamically, and of course it is, there's no added security risk in that.

Comment: The custom form isn't a redirect checkout. Using stripe/jquery.payment.js you can do all the dynamic front-end you want, while not touching the card data.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in variable if you do not reload page, and it's safe as will never go to network. However you declared ccNumber inside click function, outside of it the variable will not exists. Use global declaration like this:

```
var ccNumber;
$("#payment-next").click(function(){
   ccNumber = $("#card_number").val();
  //If credit card invalid
   if(!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNumber)){
      //Throw error 
    }
});
// here and after ccNumber will be filled after every click you can check by console.log(ccNumber)
```